# Application is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've just created a new WPF project in the blend, pushed it on git, added mqsql drivers, rest service and nfc sdk and suddenly blend tells me that Application
 is not supported. The error leads me to App.xaml which is entirely unedited and looks like this:

```
<Application x:Class="desktop_client.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:desktop_client"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

The same error goes for practically any tag such as Style, Setter, ControlTemplate, Canvas, Path. nothing is supported.
comparing both the xaml and the c# file to the other project I just finished which works just fine, there is no difference (other than namespace and the path, naturally)

I'm absolutely dumbfounded

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try adding the following references:

- PresentationCore
- PresentationFramework
- WindowsBase

With the ReferenceManager in your project.
The above references are the references used by wpf.

Comment: Thanks. System.Xaml will also be required, to build the project.

Comment: I needed WindowsFormsIntegration too.

Answer (score 74):

Had same issue in VS. I closed and restarted VS and no longer got the error.

Comment: Oftentimes the best solution.

Comment: Classic. That fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 15):

So old, still occurs - to save time for others - **this** is the solution that **works** in VS-2019, as @"Andreas Forslöw" wrote:

> Even easier: Right click the project in Solution explorer, click
> "Unload project". Then, when unloaded, right click again and click
> "**Reload project**". Worked for me! –  Andreas Forslöw

Comment: In my case VS 2019 restart (top-voted answer from @dvdhns) and even win10 reboot didn't help, but this solution worked fine!

Comment: Thank you, also reboot and restart VS2019 didn't fix this for me, but somehow unload and reload did! I was dreading having to reclone the repo just for an intellisense error.