# BindingExpression path error: 'SystemParameters'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

While updating my software, I started facing this `BindingExpression` error.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SystemParameters' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=4781813)'. BindingExpression:Path=SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=4781813); target element is 'MainWindow' (Name='XXX'); target property is 'Height' (type 'Double')

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SystemParameters' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=4781813)'. BindingExpression:Path=SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=4781813); target element is 'MainWindow' (Name='XXX'); target property is 'Width' (type 'Double')*

Reading the above error, it seems that it couldn't find the `SystemParameters` object in `MainViewModel`.

```
<Window x:Name="XXXX" x:Class="XXXX.Views.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XXXX"
    xmlns:localize="http://gu.se/Localization"
    xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:XXXX.Properties"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="1080" d:DesignWidth="1920"
    Title=""
    WindowStyle="None"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="{Binding WindowState, Mode=TwoWay}"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source ={StaticResource Locator}}"
    Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" 
    Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}" Background="#FFCCCCCC">

   <Window.Resources>
```

When I start my application, the `Initializer.cs` class is called which initializes all the parameters and creates an instance of `MainWindow`. By debugging, I discovered that the issue seems to appear when I call the method `window.Show()` and then my application crashes instantly.

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
window.Show();
```

Comment: There is obviously no public SystemParameters property in MainViewModel.

Comment: You probably wanted to write `{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}` instead of `{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}`.

Comment: @Clemens adding x:static now it is showing different error "static is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project".

Comment: @amrit2 Case-sensitvity is important, `x:Static` is not the same as `x:static` (wrong). Other than that, there might be an issue with Visual Studio, see a related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42886381/application-is-not-supported-in-a-windows-presentation-foundation-wpf-project/43793634). Try unloading and reloading the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `Binding` will resolve the property path using the `DataContext` of an element by default (which is inherited). The [`PrimaryScreenHeight`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenheight?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and [`PrimaryScreenWidth`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters.primaryscreenwidth?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) properties are `static` and part of the type [`SystemParameters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.systemparameters?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), which is a `static` type, that is not part of the data context. To solve the issue you can:

- Use the [`x:Static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.staticextension?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Markup.StaticExtension);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) markup extension to refer to static properties.

  > Implements a markup extension that returns **static field and property references**.

  ```
  Height="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}"
  Width="{x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}"
  ```
- If you need to apply a value converter, you can use the `x:Static` markup extension for the `Source`.

  ```
  Height="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
  Width="{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"
  ```